# Regarding synopsis of commands

Tags: macos, bash

I was playing with CHPASS command on my Mac OS X. I found the synopsis of CHPASS command on my bash shell and online is very different.

```
On my bash shell: chpass [-l location] [-u authname] [-s newshell] [user]
On google: chpass [-a list] [-p encpass] [-e expiretime] [-s newshell] [user]
           chpass [-oly] [-a list] [-p encpass] [-e expiretime] [-s newshell]
        [-d domain] [-h host] [user]
```

I didn't get why both synopsis are different. If I am right, do I need to update anything to get full synopsis? If yes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to think that the version of the `chpass` command you have on OS X is the same version of the command for which you found the synopsis online.  You didn't provide any links so it's hard to know for sure, but it looks like you found online the documentation for the [FreeBSD version](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chpass&sektion=1) version of the `chpass` command.

The man page for the [OS X version of the command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/chpass.1.html) shows the same synopsis you found on your computer.

These are different implementations of the `chpass` command.